# toString окончание месяца

Tags: c++, qt, дата, время

Как сделать так что бы месяц в `mmmm` был не Июль Март, а Июля Марта.

Пример: `numberDate.toString("dd.MMMM.yyyy, hh:mm.")` выведет `21.Июль.2016, 10:12`.

Вариант с MMM не подошел, где выводит Июл и добавлением "я" в конец, т.к. это жесткая привязка к конкретному месяцу. Нужно, чтобы он в зависимости от месяца сам подставлял окончание.  Можно конечно через условия сделать ведь всего 2 месяца заканчиваются на "А" - Марта и Августа в остальных случаях выводить "я", но мб есть встроенное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Конвертация даты в строку toString() использует вызов

```
QLocale::system().monthName(month, QLocale::LongFormat);
```

QLocale в процессе использует массивы

```
static const ushort months_data[] // qlocale_data_p.h
static const QLocaleData locale_data[]
```

Штатными средствами добавить окончание не получится. Так что либо писать свою функцию, либо пересобрать Qt из исходников изменив эти массивы.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, встроенного решения нет. Во всяком случае в спеках ничего об этом не говорится. Линк на [пруфы](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/).

Comment: Не сразу увидел Qt в метках, извините. Но, боюсь, как в чистом языке, там и в используемом Вами фреймворке, все упирается в ОС, которая отдает данные именно в таком виде.